# Some Edges of my Cropped Image Does not Provide the Entire Tile Based on the Shapefile

Tags: clip, rasterio

I have a shapefile and a big tiff image. I am trying to crop the tiff image based on the associated tiles of the shapefile. My problem is that I do not get the entire tile (tiles that are located in the edges of the tiff image)of the shapefile in my cropped images. It is a situation where the edge of the tiff image ends in the middle of a tile. In my code, I get the half that is in the picture but not the half in the tile. I always want to get the full.

Can you help me get the full tile?

Here is the code:

```py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.plot import plotting_extent
from rasterio.mask import mask
import earthpy as et
import earthpy.spatial as es
import earthpy.plot as ep
from pathlib import Path

shape_file = '/.../.geojson'
crop_extent = gpd.read_file(shape_file)
lidar_chm_path = '/.../reprojected.tif'
output = '/.../'

if not os.path.exists(output):
    os.mkdir(output)
i, j = 0, 0
while i < crop_extent.shape[0]:
    with rio.open(lidar_chm_path) as lidar_chm:
        try:
            lidar_chm_crop, lidar_chm_crop_meta = es.crop_image(lidar_chm,[crop_extent.iloc[i]['geometry']])
            lidar_chm_crop_affine = lidar_chm_crop_meta["transform"]
            j += 1
            lidar_chm_crop_meta.update({'transform': lidar_chm_crop_affine,
                       'height': lidar_chm_crop.shape[1],
                       'width': lidar_chm_crop.shape[2],
                        'nodata': -999.99})
            name = output + str(crop_extent.iloc[i][2]) + '_' + Path(lidar_chm_path).stem +'_' + str(j) + '.tif'
            with rio.open(name, 'w', **lidar_chm_crop_meta) as ff:
                ff.write(lidar_chm_crop[0], 1)
        except:
            None
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `all_touched=True` in your call to `crop_image` ([docs](https://earthpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/earthpy.spatial.html#earthpy.spatial.crop_image)).

Alternatively, you can do this all in `rasterio` using [`rasterio.mask.mask`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html#rasterio.mask.mask) with `all_touched=True, crop=True`.

Comment: I tried it. rasterio.mask.mask does not give me tiles in the shapefile. It only gives me the entire tif image.